# store.sync after pressed OK button only reload the store

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('RouteSeqModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: '_id', type: 'number'}, {name: 'Route_Seq' , type: 'int'},'Location_Name','Route_LocationID','Route_ID']
});

var RouteSeqStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'RouteSeqModel',
    storeId: 'RouteSeqStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    sorters: [{
                property: 'Route_Seq',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-routeseq.php',
        api: {
                create: 'insert-routeseq.php',
                //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                update: 'update-routeseq.php',
                //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
            },
        actionMethods: 'POST',
        baseParams: {
                _id : 0,
            },  
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            idProperty: '_id'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            id: '_id'

         }
    }
});
RouteSeqStore.sync({

                success: function(batch) {
                            //var button = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteSeqRefresh');
                            //button.fireEvent('click', button); //need at here , if not too fast refresh will get the old data
                            grid.setLoading(false);
                            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                title: "Information",
                                msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                fn: function(buttonId) {
                                    if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                        //load store at here
                                    }
                                }
                            });  
                },
                    failure: function(batch){
                        //var button = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteSeqRefresh');
                        //button.fireEvent('click', button); //need at here , if not too fast refresh will get the old data
                        grid.setLoading(false);
                        RouteSeqStore.rejectChanges();
                                   Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                title: "Error",
                                msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                fn: function(buttonId) {
                                    if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                        //load store at here
                                    }
                                }
                    });  

                }

            });
```

whenever called .sync function will automatically load the datastore with `get-routeseq.php`   ,
is that have any way after pressing OK button only load the datastore(after pressed OK only call the get-routeseq.php)?
my autoLoad is false, but still automatically load the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `type: 'rest'` and avoid url config in proxy.
Something like this:

```
var RouteSeqStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'RouteSeqModel',
    storeId: 'RouteSeqStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'Route_Seq',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        api: {
            create: 'insert-routeseq.php',
            read: 'get-routeseq.php',
            update: 'update-routeseq.php',
            //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
        },
        actionMethods: 'POST',
        baseParams: {
            _id : 0,
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            idProperty: '_id'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            id: '_id'

        }
    }
});
```

And if you want to just load store, use `RouteSeqStore.load()`. After you have made changes in store, use `RouteSeqStore.sync()`.